# Сhange select option to ul li

Tags: javascript, html

Phone mask selection code available.
This is necessary to display the flag of the country with the given area code mask

```js
 $(function() {
    function maskPhone() {
      var country = $('#country option:selected').val();
      switch (country) {
        case "ru":
          $("#phone").mask("+7(999) 999-99-99");
          break;
        case "by":
          $("#phone").mask("+375(99) 999-99-99");
          break;          
      }    
    }
    maskPhone();
    $('#country').change(function() {
      maskPhone();
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>

<select id="country" class="form-control">
  <option value="ru">RU +7</option>
  <option value="by">BY +375</option>

</select>
<input id="phone" type="text" name="customer_phone" value="" >
```

How to change select option to ul li ?

Comment: Welcome. What does the mask code have to do with your question? Please see [ask], then remove anything that isn't relevant to your question. Sounds like you want to convert a select box to a list. What have you tried to accomplish that?

Comment: There is a flag selection script but no mask, based on this script I want to implement a mask https://intl-tel-input.com

Answer (score 0):

You might use unicode flags:

```js
$(function() {
    function maskPhone() {
      var country = $('#country option:selected').val();
      switch (country) {
        case "ru":
          $("#phone").mask("+7(999) 999-99-99");
          break;
        case "by":
          $("#phone").mask("+375(99) 999-99-99");
          break;          
      }    
    }
    maskPhone();
    $('#country').change(function() {
      maskPhone();
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>

<select id="country" class="form-control">
  <option value="ru"> RU +7</option>
  <option value="by"> BY +375</option>

</select>
<input id="phone" type="text" name="customer_phone" value="" >
```